# Fast way to pick up certain terms in Polynomial multiplication?

Tags: list-manipulation, polynomials

I have one case (Nn=1) for 7 Polynomials as following:

```
p1= a[0]*b[0] + c[0]*d[0] + e[0]*f[0] + g[0]*h[0];
p2= a[1]*c[1] + b[1]*d[1] + e[1]*g[1] + f[1]*h[1]; 
p3= a[2]*d[2] + b[2]*c[2] + e[2]*h[2] + f[2]*g[2]; 
p4= a[3]*e[3] + b[3]*f[3] + c[3]*g[3] + d[3]*h[3]; 
p5= a[4]*f[4] + b[4]*e[4] + c[4]*h[4] + d[4]*g[4]; 
p6= a[5]*g[5] + b[5]*h[5] + c[5]*e[5] + d[5]*f[5]; 
p7= a[6]*h[6] + b[6]*g[6] + c[6]*f[6] + d[6]*e[6];
```

and I want to pick up 4 terms from the 7*4=28 terms such as `a[0]*b[0]`, `c[0]*d[0]` and so on, which gives me the output in the form of `a[x1]*b[x2]*c[x3]*d[x4]*e[x5]*f[x6]*g[x7]*h[x8]` (we can later write it as `FF[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8]`).

The way I do is as following:

```
outputstemp={};
outputs={};
FFnCaseList={a[c1_]*b[c2_]*c[c3_]*d[c4_]*e[c5_]*f[c6_]*g[c7_]*h[c8_]->FF[c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8], a[_]->0, b[_]->0, c[_]->0,  d[_]->0, e[_]->0, f[_]->0, g[_]->0, h[_]->0,  x_[_]^n_->0};

AllRows = (p1+p2+p3+p4+p5+p6+p7)^4; 
AppendTo[outputstemp, ExpandAll[AllRows]];

Timing[AppendTo[outputs, outputstemp/.FFnCaseList];]
```

> the time is `{10.2344, Null}`

**So is there any quick way to do this?** 
If I have many different cases (for example Nn=6000) of 7 Polynomials, then I can make a loop that run similar things Nn times (6000*10s). That will takes roughly 16.7 hours!!!

Any comments or suggestions are appreciated! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `Coefficient` after mopdifying so that terms of the desired form have a unique power in a new variable.

```
p1 = a[0]*b[0] + c[0]*d[0] + e[0]*f[0] + g[0]*h[0];
p2 = a[1]*c[1] + b[1]*d[1] + e[1]*g[1] + f[1]*h[1];
p3 = a[2]*d[2] + b[2]*c[2] + e[2]*h[2] + f[2]*g[2];
p4 = a[3]*e[3] + b[3]*f[3] + c[3]*g[3] + d[3]*h[3];
p5 = a[4]*f[4] + b[4]*e[4] + c[4]*h[4] + d[4]*g[4];
p6 = a[5]*g[5] + b[5]*h[5] + c[5]*e[5] + d[5]*f[5];
p7 = a[6]*h[6] + b[6]*g[6] + c[6]*f[6] + d[6]*e[6];
```

Multiply each variable by `t^2^j` where `j` is the index of that variable in the list `{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}`.

```
polys = {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7} /. 
  Thread[{v_a, v_b, v_c, v_d, v_e, v_f, v_g, v_h} -> 
    v*t^(2^Range[0, 7])]

(* Out[13]= {t^3 a[0] b[0] + t^12 c[0] d[0] + t^48 e[0] f[0] + 
  t^192 g[0] h[0], 
 t^5 a[1] c[1] + t^10 b[1] d[1] + t^80 e[1] g[1] + t^160 f[1] h[1], 
 t^6 b[2] c[2] + t^9 a[2] d[2] + t^96 f[2] g[2] + t^144 e[2] h[2], 
 t^17 a[3] e[3] + t^34 b[3] f[3] + t^68 c[3] g[3] + t^136 d[3] h[3], 
 t^18 b[4] e[4] + t^33 a[4] f[4] + t^72 d[4] g[4] + t^132 c[4] h[4], 
 t^20 c[5] e[5] + t^40 d[5] f[5] + t^65 a[5] g[5] + t^130 b[5] h[5], 
     t^24 d[6] e[6] + t^36 c[6] f[6] + t^66 b[6] g[6] + t^129 a[6] h[6]} *)
```

Pull out terms that have `t` to the power `1+2+4+...+128`, or 255. In order to speed the conversion to the `FF[...]` notation I replace sums and products by lists (this speeds otherwise slow pattern match). In a more general setting one might have to canonicalize the ordering using `Sort`.

```
Timing[
 allvarsmonoms = 
  Expand[Coefficient[(Apply[Plus, polys])^4, t^Total[2^Range[0, 7]]]];
 res0 = Apply[List, allvarsmonoms];
 res1 = res0 /. {Plus -> List, Times -> List};
 res = Apply[Plus, 
   res1 /. {num_, a[v1_], b[v2_], c[v3_], d[v4_], e[v5_], f[v6_], 
      g[v7_], h[v8_]} -> num*FF[v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8]];]
Length[res]

(* Out[71]= {0.0625, Null}

Out[72]= 105 *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! If variable in the list is `{a,b,c,d,e,f}`, should I use `v*t^(2^Range[0, 5])`?

Comment: Yes. For cleaner code, I should have defined the variable symbols in a list as `vars` and then used `Length[vars]` for that exponent.

Comment: Thank you! that speed up a lot. Very interesting!

Answer (score 5):

I am sure there is a less awkward method than the following proposal:

```
n = 4;
expr = p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 + p6 + p7;

Nest[Map[If[Signature[Head /@ (List @@ #)] == 0, 0, #] &, Expand[expr * #]] &, 1, n] /. 
(a[c1_] b[c2_] c[c3_] d[c4_] e[c5_] f[c6_] g[c7_] h[c8_]) :>
FF[c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8]
```

which yields `24 a[0] b[0] c[0] d[0] e[0] f[0] g[0] h[0] + ... 24 a[6] b[6] c[6] d[6] e[6] f[6] g[6] h[6]` in about a hundredth of the time taken for the OP's original code.

Comment: wow, that's amazing. Well, i didn't saw hundredth of time from my computer but factor of 20 is quite good! Thank you!

Comment: changing the replacement rule to `{Times -> (# FF[##2] &), 
 Alternatives[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h] -> Identity}` seems to double the speed. (+1)

Comment: @kglr, yes, that's cool! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Xuemei, your "additional" question should surely be [a separate question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @J.M., thank you very much and I have posted it as a separate question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220060/fast-way-to-apply-permutations-in-large-list). Could you have a look? would be extremely helpful and thank you a lot!

Answer (score 3):

```
expr  = p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + p5 + p6 + p7;

res = Total[Multinomial[1, 1, 1, 1] FF @@@ 
       (ReplaceAll[ _[a_] :> a] @ Select[DuplicateFreeQ @* Map[Head]]@
         Apply[Sort@*Join, Subsets[expr /. Plus|Times -> List, {4}],  {-4}])]; // 
           RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
>  .16
> ```

this gives the same result as J.M.'s approach:

```
res2 = Nest[Map[If[Signature[Head /@ (List @@ #)] == 0, 0, #] &, 
        Expand[expr*#]] &, 1, n] /. 
         (a[c1_] b[c2_] c[c3_] d[c4_] e[c5_] f[c6_] g[c7_] h[c8_]) :> 
           FF[c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8]; //  RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.54
> ```

```
res == res2
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: thank you very much and I have posted it as a separate question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220060/fast-way-to-apply-permutations-in-large-list). Could you have a look? would be extremely helpful and thank you a lot!