# Fast way to apply permutations in large list?

Tags: polynomials, expression-manipulation, permutation

I have one Polynomial in the form of `FF[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8]`, where `xi` pick numbers from `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6}` and every number has to be **appeared in even-numbered times**.

> For example `FF[0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 4, 4]` is good term we want and `FF[0, 0, 4, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]` is not (because numbers 3 and 4 all appear in odd times).

Assume one Polynomial `Poly1` as following (it can be even larger which can be obtain from [my early posted question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220007/fast-way-to-pick-up-certain-terms-in-polynomial-multiplication)):

```
Poly1 = FF[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] + FF[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1] + 
   FF[0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2] + FF[0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 3, 3] + 
   FF[0, 0, 3, 5, 2, 5, 3, 2] + FF[0, 0, 3, 6, 6, 1, 3, 1] + 
   FF[0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 4, 4] + FF[0, 0, 4, 5, 1, 5, 1, 4] + 
   FF[0, 0, 4, 6, 6, 2, 2, 4] + FF[0, 0, 5, 3, 5, 2, 2, 3] + 
   FF[0, 0, 5, 4, 5, 1, 4, 1] + FF[0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0] + 
   FF[0, 0, 6, 3, 1, 6, 1, 3] + FF[0, 0, 6, 4, 2, 6, 4, 2] + 
   FF[0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0] + FF[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0] + 
   FF[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] + FF[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2] + 
   FF[1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3] + FF[1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2] + 
   FF[1, 3, 1, 6, 6, 3, 0, 0] + FF[1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3] + 
   FF[1, 4, 1, 4, 4, 1, 4, 1] + FF[1, 4, 1, 5, 4, 5, 0, 0] + 
   FF[1, 5, 1, 4, 0, 0, 4, 5] + FF[1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5] + 
   FF[1, 5, 1, 6, 6, 2, 2, 5] + FF[1, 6, 1, 3, 0, 0, 6, 3] + 
   FF[1, 6, 1, 5, 2, 5, 6, 2] + FF[1, 6, 1, 6, 6, 1, 6, 1] + 
   FF[2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0] + FF[2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1] + 
   FF[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2] + FF[2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2] + 
   FF[2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4] + FF[2, 3, 5, 2, 5, 3, 0, 0] + 
   FF[2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 1] + FF[2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4] + 
   FF[2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6, 0, 0];
```

I assume there are Nn=6240 different Polynomials as in the form of `Poly1`. For simplicity, here I just make a loop to create such huge `Polys` as following:

```
Polys={};
Nn=6000;
For[iii= 1, iii<= Nn, iii++,AppendTo[Polys, Poly1];];
```

Then I want to permute the number sequence in the `FF[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8]` with replacements such as  `PermutNum={0->0, 1->1, 2->6, 3->2, 4->4, 5->5, 6->3}`. That means `FF[0, 0, 6, 3, 1, 6, 1, 3]` will become `FF[0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2]` after the replacement `PermutNum`.

For testing: we use the following code just for one time replacement:

```
Numlist = Range[0, 6];
PermutNumList= Permutations[Numlist];
PolysPermut={};
ReplaceCase=40; (*randomly chose one for test 1~5040*)

Timing[
   PermutNum= {};
   For[kkk = 1, kkk <= Length[Numlist], kkk++,
       AppendTo[PermutNum, Numlist[[kkk]] -> PermutNumList[[ReplaceCase]][[kkk]]];
      ];

   AppendTo[PolysPermut, Polys/.PermutNum];
]
```

> The time is `{0.671875, Null}` just for once testing.

There will be `Length[Permutations[Range[0, 6]]]=5040` replacements in total, then I apply each `PermutNum` to the huge `Polys` as following way:

```
Numlist = Range[0, 6];
PermutNumList= Permutations[Numlist];
PolysPermut={};

For[jj = 1, jj <= Length[PermutNumList], jj++,

   (*create current replacement PermutNum*)
   PermutNum= {};
   For[kkk = 1, kkk <= Length[Numlist], kkk++,
       AppendTo[PermutNum, Numlist[[kkk]] -> PermutNumList[[jj]][[kkk]]];
      ];

   AppendTo[PolysPermut, Polys/.PermutNum];

]
```

The estimated time i assumed it will be roughly **56mins**.

So is there any good solution or suggestions to **speed up such situation?** Any comments or suggestions are appreciated! Thank you very much!

Comment: I didn't look into this too much, but `Timing[PolysPermut = Replace[Polys, Dispatch@Thread[Numlist -> #], {3}] & /@ PermutNumList[[{40}]];]` is around 3 times faster on my system - the main speedup comes from [`Dispatch`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dispatch.html) and [`Replace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html) (with `{3}` to only replace on the relevant level of the expression). But probably this can be improved even further. For example: Could you somehow directly generate the permuted versions instead of having to do search-and-replace?

Comment: @LukasLang, oh, I don't know `Dispatch`exists, thanks. Well, in my case is I have in advance a large list with the numbers for `xi` randomly in the `FF[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8]`. Then I make the permutations and I am not sure how to merge them together. But good point, I will think a bit. Thank you!

Comment: @LukasLang, as an example: `tt = FF[2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];; PermutNumList[[{ReplaceCase}]] ={{0, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 2}}; yy=Replace[tt, Dispatch@Thread[Numlist -> #], {3}] & /@ PermutNumList[[{ReplaceCase}]] `; the `yy` is `{FF[2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}` not `{FF[4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}`. Seems that the replacement doesn't work. So did I miss any thing in your answer? Thank you very much!

Comment: @LukasLang, probably should not use `Replace` but `ReplaceAll`?

Comment: No, I specifically used `Replace` - of course, this only works if the structure of `Poly1` is exactly as shown. If the `FF[...]` are not all at the same depth, this might not replace all indices. But from my testing, `Replace[...,{3}]` is faster than `ReplaceAll[...]`, so I used that instead

Comment: Sorry, I missed your other comment - as noted, the `Replace[...,{3}]` style replacement will only work for expressions of the form `FF[...] + FF[...]` - for more general expressions, you do in fact need to use `ReplaceAll[...]` instead. You could e.g. use `Replace[...,{2,3}]` if you want to cover both sums of `FF[...]` and `FF[...]` alone, but I'm not sure what the performance gains are at that point.